# PFUser currentUser returns null after a few days

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parse-platform, local-storage

I'm seeing a strange problem with what appear to be invalid Parse User sessions in my app. I currently use Facebook logins in conjunction with Parse to handle new users in my app.

Using the `boilerplate` code from Parse tutorials [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users) after two days or so a call to `[PFUser currentUser]` returns null and my users are asked to login again.

To try to determine if it's related to Parse or Facebook I did the following by attempting to login with a valid Facebook Session when the     [PFuser CurrentUser] returns null and it **always seems to work**.

This makes me think it's not the Facebook session but somehow that the Parse session gets corrupted or returns something strange from time to time.  I'm sure I'm not logging out as my logout method is user driven and not called anywhere else in code.

Here's what I'm doing for authorization:

```
-(void)authorizeAndSaveUser{

//Check to see if we already have a valid PFUser to avoid authenticating again:
if(![PFUser currentUser]){

    //*Patch - occasionally the [PFUser CurrentUser] returns null when we have a logged in user.
    //My work around for this is to login with the Facebook Token if we have one

   if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){ //<- This always succeeds after the user has been created!

        // Log In (create/update currentUser) with FBSDKAccessToken
        [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
                                                    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                                        if (!user) {
                                                            NSLog(@"Uh oh. There was an error logging in with saved FB access token.");
                                                        } else {
                                                            NSLog(@"Successful login with saved FB access token.");
                                                        }
                                                    }];

    } else { // We have never logged in before so start creating a new user

        //Ask for permissions
        NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];

        // Login PFUser using Facebook
        [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error){

            if(!error){

                if (!user) { //Case where the user cancelled the login
                    NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    //The no error case - simply a cancelled login

                 } else if (user.isNew) { //Net new user
                    NSLog(@"New User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    //We have permissions so query Facebook and Write this Data to our App.
                    [self writeFacebookUserDetailsToParse];

                } else {  //Returning User
                    NSLog(@"Existing User logged in through Facebook!");

                    //We have permissions so query Facebook and Write this Data to our App in order to update profile photos etc.
                    [self writeFacebookUserDetailsToParse];
                }
            } else {  //The error case

                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                  }
           }];

    }
}
```

}

Can anyone see anything obvious or offer any advice? Although not a constant issue it's enough of a pain that every user will encounter a popup to "Re-Login" at least once a week or so...

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: Update: This seems to continue as of IOS 9. Still no solution as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this was fixed by our friends at Parse using Framework 1.9.0.  See the change-log here: https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads

> "Fixed currentUser not restoring authentication when loaded from disk."

I'll confirm if I see this again

Andrew

Comment: Hi
Let us know if fixed.
Also, Parse sample provided suggest only [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray ... for login (no word about :if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]).  Do you think it's mandatory to not have the "you have already authorized this app" screen ?

Comment: Hi Franck - I implemented the alternate login with AccessToken to try mask this issue for end users.  It addressed the case where I had a valid token and could login for them without prompting them to login again "manually".  That said it didn't work all of the time which is why I posted this.  I would remove this once we confirm the auth from disk is working as expected.  Regarding the "already authorized this app" screen - I'm not sure - I'll test this and get back to you.

Comment: Just for closure on this I'm using framework version 1.11 at this moment and after extensive testing I haven't been able to reproduce this issue.  If you are using earlier versions I would suggest upgrading to solve this issue.